# Python3 bcolors weird new line glitch when using input()

Tags: python-3.x

So I'm working on a python3 project on ubuntu and I needed colored text and with a quick google search I found that bcolors did what I needed. The only problem is, when I use it with `input()` it never makes a newline it just writes on top of itself.

This is bcolors:

```
class bcolors:
 purple = '\033[95m'
 blue = '\033[94m'
 green = '\033[92m'
 yellow = '\033[93m'
 red = '\033[91m'
 cyan = '\033[96m'
 white = '\033[97m'
 grey = '\033[90m'
 end = '\033[0m'
 bold = '\033[1m'
 underline = '\033[4m'
```

Example:

Input

```
while True:
   x = input('{}input {}'.format(bcolors.green, bcolors.end))
   print(x)
```

when you run out of space on the first line:

```
 oddut it is really odd it is really odd it is really odd it is really
```

instead of

```
input it is really odd it is really odd it is really odd it is really it is really odd
```

[image]
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "when you type more than one line"? Please give an example.

Comment: is that more clear?

Comment: I still do not see "more than one line." It is still one line in your example.

Comment: Can you share the complete code? It is not clear how you are creating new lines here since typing `Enter` after giving an input will simply close the program.

Comment: I added a loop so it never closes my actual use requires json and it would be difficult to recreate and have it make sense

Answer (score 0):

Simply you should surround nonprinting escape sequences with `\x01`(SOH) and `\x02`(STX).

demo:

[image]

code snippet for the demo:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re
import readline

def color(x):
    return '\033[92m' + x + '\033[0m'

def escape(x):
    return re.sub(r'(\033\[[\d;]+m)',
                  r'\001\1\002', x)

input(color('colored: '))
input(escape(color('escaped: ')))
```